# curvyObject warning: zero-width box with no accountable parent IE8-7

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using curvey corner to round div .. but i am getting error in ie7-8 i have searched but could not get exact answer.. i found that its due to the html5 tags i used

```
curvyObject warning:
zero-width box with no accountable parent
tag: NAV
id: nav-main
class: search-popup searchBox
Parent tag: DIV
Parent class: container
```

here is the code which contains class search-popup searchBox

```
<div class="search-popup searchBox">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-search-type="product">Search For Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-search-type="service">Search For Services</a></li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution as of now. this warning is due to the div which are display none so curvey corner throws warning.

```
.search-popup searchBox
{
display:none;
}
```

i removed this css and applied using jquery

`$(".search-popup").hide()` in ready

now it working fine